# custom varwidth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df = data.frame(a = c(0, 0), b = c(17, 15), 
                c = c(35,37), d = c(55,57), 
                e = c(80, 85), x = c(1, 2), 
                w1 = c(20, 30), w2 = c(0.2, 0.3))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = x, ymin = a, lower = b, middle = c, upper = d, ymax = e),
               stat = "identity")
```

I have a dataframe containing the values of each quantile for a boxplot, (a-e).
Is it possible use columns w1 or w2 to define the width of the boxplots in ggplot?

My desired result is similar to using `varwidth` in `graphics::boxplot` but with custom widths.

```
graphics::boxplot(mpg~gear, mtcars, varwidth = T)
```

Don't think this is a duplicate since it seems like the `weight` argument doesn't work with `stat = identity`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R ggplot2 boxplot - varying box width by a function/vector values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764139/r-ggplot2-boxplot-varying-box-width-by-a-function-vector-values)

Comment: After some quick testing, it looks like this is not a dupe of that question - the `weight` argument doesn't seem to work when using `stat = "identity"` to do everything manually.

Comment: Yes i have seen that topic, it seems like weight argument dosen't work with `stat = identity`. Since `geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE)` work when the quantiles are not pre-defined. Is it possible that the widths are stored somewhere in the `ggplot` object?

Comment: You need to use a `width` aesthetic, I think: `width = w1`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it can be done by using `stat_summary`.

```
df = data.frame(a = c(0, 0), b = c(17, 15), 
            c = c(35,37), d = c(55,57), 
            e = c(80, 85), x = factor(c(1, 2)), 
            w = c(0.2, 0.3))

df2 = reshape2::melt(data = df, id = "x")

ff = function(x){
  data.frame(
    ymin = x[1],
    lower = x[2],
    middle = x[3],
    upper = x[4],
    ymax = x[5],
    width = x[6]
  )
}

ggplot(df2, aes(x, value)) + stat_summary(fun.data = ff, geom = "boxplot")
```

But i am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: can you explain why melting and give some details about your `ff` function.